# Suppress error messages in Windows commandline

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file

Let's say I already have a folder created on the next path file: `"C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder"`, and I run the next command on CMD:

```
mkdir "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder"
```

I get a message like this: **"A subdirectory or file C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder already exists"**.

Therefore, is there any command in the commandline to get rid of this returned messages? 
I tried echo off but this is not what I looking for.

Comment: Easy enough..  `IF NOT EXIST "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder\." mkdir "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder"`

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Redirect the output to `nul`

```
mkdir "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder" > nul
```

Depending on the command, you may also need to redirect errors too:

```
mkdir "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder" > nul 2> nul
```

[Microsoft describes the options here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx), which is useful reading.

Comment: So, if I use only once > nul, this will get me rid of warnings, and if I use > nul 2 > nul, this will get me rid of warnings and errors, am I right?

Comment: Yes, strictly speaking `>nul` redirects `stdout` and `2>nul` redirects `stderr`, which are the two output streams you usually see in a command window. Which one(s) is(are) used depends on the command itself.

Comment: To the OP, the second redirection can be `2>&1` which will send STDERR to the same place that STDOUT is already being redirected to.  It's used more often in practice than using >nul twice, so you'll see it in code.

Comment: 2>nul mkdir "C:\users\charqus\desktop\MyFolder" is also possible and this style was required in teamcity

Answer (score 6):

A previous answer shows how to squelch all the output from the command. This removes the helpful error text that is displayed if the command fails. A better way is shown in the following example:

```
C:\test>dir
     Volume in drive C has no label.
     Volume Serial Number is 4E99-B781

     Directory of C:\test

    20/08/2015  20:18    <DIR>          .
    20/08/2015  20:18    <DIR>          ..
                   0 File(s)              0 bytes
                   2 Dir(s)  214,655,188,992 bytes free

C:\test>dir new_dir >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir

C:\test>dir new_dir >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir
```

As is demonstrated above this command successfully suppress the original warning. However, if the directory can not be created, as in the following example:

```
C:\test>icacls c:\test /deny "Authenticated Users":(GA)
processed file: c:\test
Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files

C:\test>dir new_dir2 >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir2 >nul 2>nul || mkdir new_dir2
Access is denied.
```

Then as can be seen, an error message is displayed describing the problem.