# Capturing results of system() in C in Windows OS?

Tags: c, winapi

When using the `system()` function in C code, it appears that in many cases that it doesn't provide `errno` results but exit codes or simply writes to `stdout` and `stderr`.

My question is how can I get the results from `system()` before they go to `stdout` or `stderr`? Can the output be piped to a C function. I read this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) provided in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298682/suppress-error-messages-in-windows-commandline) but am not sure.

I think `stdout` and `stderr` can be redirected to a file and read from there but is there a better way to capture the output?

Also, is the text file layout consistent between OS versions, and where can that information be found?

For a simple example, could the results of `system( "dir > dirList" )` be programmatically captured in C to build a custom listing? I know that there is are `readdir()` and `stat()` in the `dirent.h` header to get this information but it's just an example to illustrate.

Thank you.

Comment: What you want is `popen()`, but I don't know to what extent Windows supports it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/popen-wpopen?view=msvc-160

Comment: For Windows specifically, see also [Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output) and this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35969730/how-to-read-output-from-cmd-exe-using-createprocess-and-createpipe).